# Internal redirection to another domain in Apache

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, proxy

I have spent a good amount of time reading the docs and making this to work, but still no chance. Maybe I can get help here.

I have two domains on the same server. domainPublic.com and domainPrivate.com

Some of images are hosted on domainPrivate.com but I want to show to public as those images are hosted on domainPublic.com

So far, I have tried all of the following, but none worked:

```
<Directory /var/www/vhosts/domainprivate.com/admin/upload/>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

RewriteRule ^/admin/upload/(.*)$ /var/www/vhosts/domainprivate.com/admin/upload/$1 [L]

# and

Alias /admin/upload/ /var/www/vhosts/domainprivate.com/admin/upload/

# and

RewriteRule /admin/upload/ http://domainprivate.com/admin/upload/ [P] 

# and
#in vhost file

ProxyPass /admin/upload/ http://domainprivate.com/admin/upload/
```

The exact URL that I am trying to access is as follows

```
http://www.domainpublic.com/admin/upload/subdir/image_0010.jpg
```

`mod_proxy` is enabled.
What I am missing here? Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you should have been close with one of the answers. However, with the P flag you need to also match the full URI and capture it and use the backreference in the substitution string. Give this a try.

```
RewriteRule ^/?admin/upload/(.+)$ http://domainprivate.com/admin/upload/$1 [P]
```